# Can't run 'flutter pub get' because my sdk version is lower then it should be

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I have a problem in project.
I want to migrate to flutter with null-safty.
But when i want to run 'flutter pub get' i get message -

> The current Dart SDK version is 2.12.0-133.2.beta.

> Because flutter_shareit requires SDK version >=2.12.0 <3.0.0, version solving failed.
> pub upgrade failed (1; Because flutter_shareit requires SDK version >=2.12.0 <3.0.0, version solving failed.)

My flutter and dart version is

> Flutter 2.0.5 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
> Framework • revision adc687823a (4 days ago) • 2021-04-16 09:40:20 -0700
> Engine • revision b09f014e96
> Tools • Dart 2.12.3

I tried using `flutter clean`, but still everything stays the same

My pubspec.yaml

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  flutter_icons: ^1.1.0
  dots_indicator: ^2.0.0
  flutter_staggered_grid_view: ^0.4.0
  flutter_point_tab_bar: ^0.2.0
  splashscreen: ^1.3.5




dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_launcher_icons: "^0.8.1"

flutter_icons:
  image_path: "assets/icons/logoo.png"   
  android: true
  ios: true

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true

  assets:
    - assets/images/friends/
    - assets/images/posts/
    - assets/images/saved/
    - assets/images/story/
    - assets/images/splash/
  #   - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg

  fonts:
    - family: Ubuntu-Regular
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/Ubuntu-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
```

Comment: i discovered thath after running 'flutter doctor' i got 
[√] Flutter (Channel beta, 1.25.0-8.1.pre, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.928], locale pl-PL)
    • Flutter version 1.25.0-8.1.pre at C:\src\flutter\flutter
    • Framework revision 8f89f6505b (4 months ago), 2020-12-15 15:07:52 -0800
    • Engine revision 92ae191c17
    • Dart version 2.12.0 (build 2.12.0-133.2.beta)

Comment: I reinstalled flutter and it works fine

Answer (score 1):

Set the sdk to `">=2.10.0 <3.0.0"`. Switch to stable and then upgrade flutter to 2.0.

After that you should go through all your packages and upgrade them to null safety first.

Just follow the [migration guide](https://dart.dev/null-safety/migration-guide) for more details

Answer (score 0):

try running the following:

1. `flutter pub outdated`
2. `flutter pub --major-version`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you download the new flutter version in the same path of the previous one.
If you download it in another path then you should change your Environment path of flutter into the new one.

Answer (score -2):

I just changed my file names

- **Home_Screen.dart** to **homescreen_dart** and
- **Drawer.dart** to **drawer_widget.dart**.

Hope it's Helpful.

Comment: File names have no effect on this issue.